# how to systemd mount nfs share

Tags: permissions, mount, systemd, nfs

I mounted a nfs share using systemd and it all works but only for the root user. How can I mount using systemd that the mountpoint can be accessed by all users and is also usable by a docker container?

At the moment I can only access the mountpoint as root user, any other user gets a `Permission denied`. Here is my config:

```
[Unit]
Description=NZBGet
After=network.target

[Mount]
What=192.168.2.32:/volume1/nzbget
Where=/mnt/synology/nzbget
Type=nfs
Options=soft,async

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Regardless of how it's mounted, access to an NFS filesystem is determined by UID afaik. For simple configurations you can arrange for UIDs to match between the client and server; otherwise you can set up user-mapping - see for example [SettingUpNFSHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo#NFS_server) and/or `man idmapd.conf`

Comment: Thanks for the hint of the UIDs. This got me in the right direction. I needed to configure squash on the nfs share, the mount itself was completely OK!

Comment: Reminder: NFS4 has more options for access control than the UID !